# How to delete files from directory using CSV in bash

Tags: bash, csv, find, rm

I have 600,000+ images in a directory. The filenames look like this:

```
1000000-0.jpeg
1000000-1.jpeg
1000000-2.jpeg
1000001-0.jpeg
1000002-0.jpeg
1000003-0.jpeg
```

The first number is a unique ID and the second number is an index.

```
{unique-id}-{index}.jpeg
```

How would I load the `unique-id`'s in from a .CSV file and remove each file whose Unique ID matches the Unique ID's in the .CSV file?

The CSV file looks like this:

```
1000000
1000001
1000002
```

... or I can have it separated by semicolons like so (if necessary):

```
1000000;1000001;1000002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the IFS variable to `;` and loop over the values read into an array:

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=';' read -a ids ; do
    for id in "${ids[@]}" ; do
        rm $id-*.jpg
    done
done < file.csv
```

Try running the script with `echo rm ...` first to verify it does what you want.

Comment: Hey guys, I know it has been a while, but I'm using this for garbage collection and I didn't actually need it until now. I just wanted to make sure that this works. The output for this is returning `rm: cannot remove '1477187'$'\r''-*.jpeg': No such file or directory`. Can anyone tell me where the `'$'\r''` is coming from? This would work if only I could figure out how to remove that string from the command.

Comment: @ihodonald: Have you created the input file on MSWin? Just run `fromdos` or `dos2unix` on the input to turn its line ends into the *nix ones.

Answer (score 0):

If there's exactly one ID per line, this will show you all matching file names:

```
ls | grep -f unique-ids.csv
```

If that list looks correct, you can delete the files with:

```
ls | grep -f unique-ids.csv | xargs rm
```

Caveat: This is a quick and dirty solution. It'll work if the file names are all named the way you say. Beware it could easily be tricked into deleting the wrong things by a clever attacker or a particularly hapless user.

Comment: I tried this and my shell basically gave me an infinite flashing cursor (never gave me any output). It could be because I'm using Git Bash on Windows 10. I haven't had much trouble with it besides the binaries being a little bit older on Windows.

Comment: To clarify: `ls | grep -f unique-ids.csv` gave me no output.

Comment: This just gave me a grep: memory exhausted code:

`$ ls | grep -f journal.csv
36869456-0.jpeg
...
grep: memory exhausted`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` and `sed`:

```
find dir -regextype posix-egrep \
         -regex ".*($(sed 's/\;/|/g' ids.csv))-[0-9][0-9]*\.jpeg"
```

replace `dir` with your search directory, and `ids.csv` with your CVS file. To delete the files you could include `-delete` option.

Comment: I updated the answer. I assumed `ids.csv` is a single-line file separated by semicolons.

Comment: Give me just a moment and I will try this. There are a lot of files and it's hard to pinpoint one that actually needs to be deleted.

Comment: I apologize. For some reason or another, the program that I was using (MySQL) that was supposed to create a semicolon-separated CSV file was not actually separating the fields by a semicolon ?:\ weird. I know. Nevertheless, the solution given by @choroba above works just fine. I just substituted the semicolon in the IFS variable with "\n". Thank Perhaps I will try this again if I can figure out how to use it on a CSV with \n delimiter.

Comment: I tried to use Sublime Text to insert semicolons manually but it froze when I tried to insert semicolons on 50,000+ rows.